# Out of Memory Message box

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I have an MFC application developed with VS2003
It is working fine in XP vista etc.
But when i have executed it in windows 8, and we use it for some time,
then no window is displayed. Instead of that the a MessageBox with a message 'Out of Memory' is displayed. And the Message box is Having the caption of my application.

This issue is rarely occurred in windows 7 too.
I have tried watching the handles using tools like processexplorer and it is not increasing.
Also many forums says that it is because of increase in unclosed handles or resources.

Can any one suggest how can i find where the issue is. Or any one provide possible reason for this.

I cant setup the devenv in the machine causing the issue. I am confused how to diagnose by executing a test build in that.

Please provide your findings.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure case of memory leak. Let me tell you MFC exe changes his memory allocation from version to version. There may be your xp machine not showing the message box but issue is there.

Comment: Best way is debug it or use message box debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have a memory leak somewhere. It's hard to be any more specific without seeing the code.

A debugger is really the best way to solve this problem. If you can reproduce the problem on your development machine, that would be the easiest case. If not, you can attach a debugger to the running process on another machine, either locally or remotely.

The MFC libraries also support some basic [memory leak detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c99kz476.aspx), turned on by default for Debug builds and controllable for other builds using the `AfxEnableMemoryTracking` function. You can use this feature to obtain information about which blocks of memory were allocated but not properly deallocated (i.e. were leaked).

Like you mentioned, Process Explorer is another good way to track down resource leaks. Are you *sure* that the handle counts are remaining constant rather than trending upwards over time? If the values in the columns are *never changing* like the question suggests, then you are surely doing something wrong. Your application *has* to be creating objects in order to do its job. The point is to make sure that it disposes of them when it is finished.

If you can't reproduce the problem with the running application and have *only* the source code available, you'll need to go through the code and make sure that every use of `new` has a corresponding use of `delete` (and that `new[]` matches up with `delete[]`). And in general in C++, you should avoid explicit dynamic memory allocation wherever possible. Instead, use the container classes that are provided either by MFC or the standard library. For example, don't allocate arrays manually, use `std::vector` to do it for you. These container classes ensure that the memory is automatically deallocated in the destructor when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The application's memory usage is around 4MB at the time of the issue. And before that it was varying in between 3.5 to 5 MBs...